# @Recover is not working for custom exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

The following retry is working fine. The recover method got invoked after 3 failed tries

```
@Retryable(value = MyException.class)
public String getSomething(String performanceId) {
    String s = "test";
     ...
     throw new MyException("test", new RuntimeException());
     ...
    return s;
 }

@Recover
public String recover(MyException exception, String performanceId) {
     log.info("In recover method!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
     return "test";
}
```

But the following recover method will not be invoked when I changed the return type. Can you please tell why and how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

```
@Retryable(value = MyException.class)
public MyOwnType getSomething(String performanceId) {
    MyOwnType s = new MyOwnType();
     ...
     throw new MyException("test", new RuntimeException());
     ...
    return s;
 }

@Recover
public MyOwnType recover(MyException exception, String performanceId) {
     log.info("In recover method!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
     return new MyOwnType();
}
```

---

```
public class MyOwnType implements Serializable {
...
}
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I am throwing a custom exception as well

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

Comment: Iam facing the same issue with custom exception type but found no solution...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me; are you sure you have `@EnableRetry`?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So69916559Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69916559Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Test test) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(test.getSomething("foo"));
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Test {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    @Retryable(value = RuntimeException.class)
    public MyOwnType getSomething(String performanceId) {
        MyOwnType s = new MyOwnType();
        log.info("here");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Recover
    public MyOwnType recover(RuntimeException exception, String performanceId) {
        log.info("In recover method!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        return new MyOwnType();
    }

}

class MyOwnType implements Serializable {

}
```

Result

```
here
here
here
In recover method!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
com.example.demo.MyOwnType@3f725306
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I have all necessary annotations. Otherwise, the first case wouldn't work. I forgot to mention I am throwing custom exception which may wrap different exception types. I suspect that may be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by changing the recover method to

```
@Recover
public MyOwnType recover(RuntimeException exception, String performanceId) {
     log.info("In recover method!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
     return new MyOwnType();
}
```

Even though MyException extends RuntimeException. The recover method will not be invoked if it is expecting MyException. Not sure why